# Unsupported method: AndroidProject.getPluginGeneration()

Tags: android

i try to use 1.0.2 ide,because i took over the old program of the app ,and i update to 2.3.3,cause the error ,i dont want to use 1.0.2 IDE.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'xxxxx'
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 8
        versionName '1.7'
    }
```

I try to change buildToolsVersion to 21.0.0 , the problem solved!
finally ,you should check you buildtool version downdoad to 21.0.0 ,and you must to check gradle app buildtoolsversion !

i delay the problem cause i used to use eclispe and the jars are different, so perhaps double check your  complesdkversion and build toolversion, you have to check and carefully .

> Unsupported method: AndroidProject.getPluginGeneration(). The version
>   of Gradle you connect to does not support that method. To resolve the
>   problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you
>   connect to. Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read
>   other information from the model.
>   org.gradle.tooling.model.UnsupportedMethodException: Unsupported
>   method: AndroidProject.getPluginGeneration(). The version of Gradle
>   you connect to does not support that method. To resolve the problem
>   you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
>   Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other
>   information from the model.   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.model.internal.Exceptions.unsupportedMethod(Exceptions.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$InvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:342)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy145.getPluginGeneration(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.android.tools.idea.fd.gradle.InstantRunGradleUtils.getIrSupportStatus(InstantRunGradleUtils.java:49)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.canInstantRun(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:686)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getState(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:420)
>     at
>   com.intellij.execution.runners.ExecutionEnvironment.getState(ExecutionEnvironment.java:158)
>     at
>   com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:55)
>     at
>   com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:31)
>     at
>   com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:50)
>     at
>   com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:31)
>     at
>   com.intellij.execution.ProgramRunnerUtil.executeConfiguration(ProgramRunnerUtil.java:121)
>     at
>   com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.start(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:116)
>     at
>   com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.access$400(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:67)
>     at
>   com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$7.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:516)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>     at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:378)    at
>   com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.run(Alarm.java:398)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   com.intellij.util.concurrency.SchedulingWrapper$MyScheduledFutureTask.run(SchedulingWrapper.java:227)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)   at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:658)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: Seems like a gradle plugin version issue..  Check if the version of gradle plugin is `2.3.0-beta2` and post your `build.gradle` files as well

Comment: solved change gradle buildtoolversion and download the toolversion.

Comment: its version issue actually! hope all of the guys dont touch the problem

Answer (score -1):

It can occur because AS was checking availability of the Instant Run feature. The fixed is to disable Instant Run:

Windows & Linux:

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run.
Mac:

Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run.